# MySQL - Multi SELECTs em uma query

Tags: mysql, select

Eu preciso obter todas as colunas de uma tabela e mais uma coluna personalizada na mesma query, eu tentei deste modo:

```
SELECT (SELECT * FROM clans WHERE ID=1), (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM contas WHERE Clan=1) AS Membros;
```

Está dando erro por tentar obter mais de uma coluna por SELECT.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido.

```
SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM contas WHERE Clan=1) AS Membros FROM clans WHERE ID=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar JOIN para deixar mais simples sua query:

```
SELECT  
    c.*,
    COUNT(cn.Clan) AS membros
FROM clans c
INNER JOIN contas cn
ON cn.Clan = c.ID
WHERE c.ID = 1
GROUP BY c.ID
```